# What to do when my CNN model does not change its accuracy and loss and outputs the same prediction in any input images

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm currently working on creating an image classifier of images that uses steganography. But the model that I've created (which is based on [this](https://github.com/rcouturier/steganalysis_with_CNN_for_same_key_images) model) doesn't change its accuracy and loss.

I created my own dataset. my testing dataset contains ~4000 images of each steganographic algorithms which are *F5, outguess, jsteg* plus the 4000 images without any steganographic materials inside having a total of 10000 images. The images with steganography only contains texts inside like *"this is a secret message"*. All the images are *512x512* in size and rgb.

This is how I created my model

```
    def createModel(self):

        self.model = Sequential()

        self.model.add(Conv2D(3,(3,3), input_shape=(self.IMAGE_SIZE,self.IMAGE_SIZE,3)))
        self.model.add(Activation('relu'))

        self.model.add(Conv2D(64,(509,509)))
        self.model.add(Activation('relu'))

        self.model.add(Flatten())
        # self.model.add(Dropout(0.4))
        # self.model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

and this is how I do the training

```
    def trainModel(self):

        X_train,y_train = self.getTrainingData()
        X_test,y_test = self.getTestingData()


        run_opts = tf.RunOptions(report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom = True)
        self.model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer='sgd',
              metrics=['accuracy'], options = run_opts)

        self.model.fit(
            X_train, 
            y_train, 
            batch_size=1, 
            validation_data=(X_test, y_test), 
            epochs=5)
        self.model.summary()
        score = self.model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
        print('Test loss:', score[0])
        print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

What I've already tried:

1. Increase the *epochs* and *batch_size*
2. change the optimizer from *Adam* to *sgd*
3. change the learning rate
4. increase the number of kernels
5. change the activation(from *relu* to *tanh* to *relu*)
6. add dense layer of 64 to 254 to 512 then comment it out

I'm using *python 3.5.2*, *tensorflow 1.15.0*, *ubuntu 16.04*, *keras 2.2.4*

please help me. I need this for my project.

here's my [repository](https://github.com/jragustin/SP-SEEN) which contains the dataset plus the whole code

[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRMat.png) to see the image of the model.summary
And here is one of the summary output

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
______________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape                   Param #
======================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 510, 510, 3)            84
______________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 510, 510, 3)            0
______________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 2, 2, 64)               49743616
______________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 2, 2, 64)               0
______________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 256)                    0
______________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 256)                    0
______________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 512)                    131584
______________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 3)                      1539
======================================================================
Total params: 49,876,823
Trainable params: 49,876,823
Non-trainable params: 0
______________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: could you **print(model.summary())** ?

Comment: The second convolution layer that you have used has a huge filter size 509*509; Please correct it by reducing it. Use 5*5 in Layer 1 of 2D CNN and use 3*3 in Layer 2 of 2D CNN

Comment: [here's the summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRMat.png) @BenjaminBreton

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa, why is it wrong to have huge filter?

Comment: @JericoAgustin please copy paste the summary to your question

Comment: @Jerico, the usual pattern is to have larger filters in the starting layer and smaller filters in the layers towards the end

Comment: @BenjaminBreton, alright done sir.

Comment: Aside of the correctness of the code, you said you embedded a short message. The size of the message is what creates statistical disturbances that differentiate it from a clean cover medium. The link you included, and the paper therein, mention 0.1 bpp, which I understand to mean embedding size of 0.1 bits per pixel. For a 512x512 image that's about 3k bytes.

Comment: yes you're right sir @Reti43, but may I ask, what are you trying to point out?

Comment: If you introduce too few disturbances, your stego image will be indistinguishable from a normal image. Are you certain your model has the power to tell the difference?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure, @Reti43. But that does make sense. Thank you

Comment: @Reti43, but still doesn't change it's accuracy. I already tried running it for 30 epochs, same accuracy, same loss.